# C Prime Number crashes at 64901

Tags: c, function, recursion

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define size 20000000

int prim[size];
int  i, zahl, zaehler, erg;


int sieve(int zahl, int prim[], int zaehler) {
    if(zahl == 2000000)
        return 1;

    for(i=0; i<=zaehler; i++) {
        erg = zahl%prim[i];

        if(erg==0) {
            zahl++;
            return sieve(zahl, prim, zaehler);
        }   
    }           

    zaehler++;
    prim[zaehler]=zahl;
    zahl++;
    printf("%d\n", prim[zaehler]);
    return sieve(zahl, prim, zaehler);      
}

int main(){

    zaehler = 0;
    zahl = 2;       

    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        prim[i]=2;

    sieve(zahl, prim, zaehler);
}
```

When trying to calculate prime numbers, when i run this code, it always crushes at the number 64901.
What might be the problem?

Comment: Wellcome to SO. This is a perfect oportunity for you to learn how to debug your own programs. You'd learn much more from it than if anybody else finds your error.

Comment: "It always crushes at the number 64901" is not much use as a description of the error you're seeing. Does it say "Error #so-and-so"? "Segmentation fault"? Does it just stop as if it ran successfully? etc.

Comment: If you have a 1MB stack size, you will hit the bottom after about that number of recursions.

Comment: "crushes" -> "crashes". :) As Bo suggests, I suspect you've run out of stack. A non-recursive approach would be better for `sieve`. Recursion can be convenient and possibly more transparent at times, but it has its serious drawbacks if not managed carefully.

Comment: If you're using Linux, say, you can use `valgrind` to debug the memory problems in the program. `valgrind ./myprogram`.

Answer (score 1):

Ironically, this is literally a stack overflow due to recursion. You can make your stack large (which will only delay the issue), or change from a recursive solution to an iterative one.

(and for what it's worth, some debuggers won't be able to help you in this situation. And it's very difficult to beginners in C to understand what is going wrong until the first time they hit this problem. So congrats! You're leveling up in C)

A cheap way to verify it's indeed a stack overflow is to create extra memory on your stack in the recursive function and see if the number it crashes on changes from 64901. My guess is if you put like `char dummy[2048]` in there, it will crash much sooner.

Comment: Compilers are likely to remove unused arrays such as `char dummy[2048]` during optimization. Perhaps recommend that optimization be turned off, the program be run to establish a baseline, and then the dummy space inserted and the program be rerun.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Or just `strcpy()` in some random data.

Comment: @anonymoose: Trying to outsmart a compiler in these things is tricky. Even if you use `strcpy` to copy some data into `dummy`, the compiler can see it is not used and remove both `dummy` and `strcpy` because they have no visible effects (as defined in the C standard). However, if you declared `dummy` as `volatile char dummy[2048]`, then you could simply write zeros to it with `memset`, and the compiler would be required to actually do the writes.

Comment: watch out for the super smart compilers that decides your entire project is pointless and optimize the whole thing away /s

Comment: @TinyTheBrontosaurus: You kid, but in some cases, you actually do need to watch out for exactly that. If your program has no observable behavior, you might legally get nothing but an empty `main`.